# tikz rotate 3d arrowhead mark

Tags: tikz-arrows, rotating, 3d

[image: screenshot] I just bodged this together using internet code samples, but I have a problem: I want the ticks at the end of the 'a' bar to be parallel to the ground, not be angled perpendicularly to the line. Is there any possibility of achieving that?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},x=3.85mm,z=-1cm, scale=0.5]
      \draw (2,-3,-1) coordinate (x) |- (-2,3,-1) coordinate [midway] (h) coordinate (y) -- (-2,3,1) coordinate (a) -- (-2,-3,1) coordinate (z) -- (2,-3,1) edge (x) -- (2,3,1) coordinate (v) edge (h)
      -- (a)  ;
      \draw [dashed] (-2,-3,-1) coordinate (o) edge (x) edge (y) -- (z);
      \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node [midway,above] {$x$};
      \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node [midway,right] {$y$};
      \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node [midway,above] {$z$};

      \draw [|-|] (2, 3.5, -1) -- (-2, 3.5, -1) node[midway, below right] {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You could use `[<->]` in the last `\draw` command, to avoid the perpendicular lines.  But the even then, the arrows are tilted. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to draw the horizontal lines yourself, replacing

```
\draw [|-|] (2, 3.5, -1) -- (-2, 3.5, -1) node[midway, below right] {a};
```

by

```
\draw ( 2, 3.4,-1) -- ( 2, 3.6,-1);
\draw (-2, 3.4,-1) -- (-2, 3.6,-1);
\draw ( 2, 3.5,-1) -- node[right]{a} (-2, 3.5,-1) ;
```

Note that you can avoid all the `midway`s by placing the `node` after the line operator instead of after the end coordinate.

Comment: already thought of that, but is not a very nice solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to manage it by just one command, but you can draw the ticks as seperate lines:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},x=3.85mm,z=-1cm, scale=0.5]
      \draw (2,-3,-1) coordinate (x) |- (-2,3,-1) coordinate [midway] (h) coordinate (y) -- (-2,3,1) coordinate (a) -- (-2,-3,1) coordinate (z) -- (2,-3,1) edge (x) -- (2,3,1) coordinate (v) edge (h)
      -- (a)  ;
      \draw [dashed] (-2,-3,-1) coordinate (o) edge (x) edge (y) -- (z);
      \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node [midway,above] {$x$};
      \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node [midway,right] {$y$};
      \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node [midway,above] {$z$};

      \draw [-] (2, 3.5, -1) -- (-2, 3.5, -1) node[midway, below right] {a};
      \draw [-] (2, 3.75, -1) -- (2, 3.3, -1);
      \draw [-] (-2, 3.7, -1) -- (-2, 3.25, -1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In this form, it's not really handy if you want to change the coordinates because you have to change them for three instead of one line. If thats a problem, you can work with two nodes and relative coordinates, so you only have to change the two variables.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},x=3.85mm,z=-1cm, scale=0.5]
      \draw (2,-3,-1) coordinate (x) |- (-2,3,-1) coordinate [midway] (h) coordinate (y) -- (-2,3,1) coordinate (a) -- (-2,-3,1) coordinate (z) -- (2,-3,1) edge (x) -- (2,3,1) coordinate (v) edge (h)
      -- (a)  ;
      \draw [dashed] (-2,-3,-1) coordinate (o) edge (x) edge (y) -- (z);
      \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node [midway,above] {$x$};
      \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node [midway,right] {$y$};
      \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node [midway,above] {$z$};

    \node (a1) at (-2, 3.5, -1){};
    \node (a2) at (2, 3.5, -1){};
    \draw [-] (a1.center) -- (a2.center) node[midway, below right] {a};
    \draw [-] (a1.center) -- +(0,-0.25,0) -- +(0,0.2,0);
    \draw [-] (a2.center) -- +(0,-0.2,0) -- +(0,0.25,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

These two samples should both look like this:

[image: TikZ-Sample]

Comment: gernot was a little bit faster, but perhaps the idea with nodes will bring a benefit. Sorry for the similar answer, doesn't see the other one before posting mine...